# Determining when layer visibility is turned ON or OFF (changed) in QGIS plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I need to update a vector layer's data when the visibility is turned back on.  My update does not occur when the visibility is off.

To what signal do I need to connect to catch the visibility change?

Answer (score 5):

An example to complete [@snaileaters's anwser](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/151243/115) :

```
def print_informations(layerTreeNode, checkstate):
'''print some informations when a group or a layer is checked'''
    if checkstate:
        if layerTreeNode.nodeType() == 0:
            print "Group " + layerTreeNode.name()
        else:
            if layerTreeNode.nodeType() == 1:
                print "Layer " + layerTreeNode.layerName()
            else:
                print "Error"

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
root.visibilityChanged.connect(print_informations)
```

Answer (score 2):

the **visibilityChanged** signal of a *QgsLayerTreeNode* object should do the job i think.

Comment: My answer only applies when checking/unchecking group/layer in **the Layer Tree view** not when layers appear/disappear due to a scale based visibility setting ...

Comment: This may help. How do I get the TreeNode from the layer?