# Getting signal when toggling group in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, table-of-contents

I have a group which contains x number of layers. I can connect the group's node [visibilityChanged](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeNode.html#acd8ebad3e3fc5b7f8ac7f500a50ca12f) signal to a simple print function so that when the group is toggled, a message is printed to the console.

The issue is that the message is printed x times (the number of layers in the group) + 1 (the group node itself).

Is there a signal which is only **emitted once** when the group node is toggled?

I tried searching in the [QgsLayerTreeGroup](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeGroup.html) and [QgsLayerTreeNode](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeNode.html) classes but I seemed to have missed it.

---

A simple example:

```
def print_me():
    print 'something'

group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findGroup('myGroup')
group.visibilityChanged.connect(print_me)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: check this example https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/177984/49538

Comment: @FranciscoRaga - Thanks for the link, looks useful. Will test it out :)